# How to create uninstaller shortcut using WIX

Tags: wix

I have created a simple silent installer with no ui for my application using WIX. I want to have an uninstaller link which removes all the directories and registry entry created during installation of application. I am getting no idea how to accomplish this. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [special topic for your case in WiX manual](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/create_uninstall_shortcut.html).